# How to apply an SLD containing WKT to symbology in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, well-known-text

I have an SLD symbology code in GeoServer

Here's how it looks in GeoServer.

[image]

```
<se:Rule>
<se:Name>Single symbol</se:Name>
<se:PolygonSymbolizer>
<se:Fill>
<se:GraphicFill>
<se:Graphic>
<se:Mark>
<se:WellKnownName>wkt://MULTILINESTRING((0 0, 0.1 0.1), (0.2 0.15, 0.3 0.15), (0.4 0.1, 0.5 0), (0.25 0.2, 0.2 0.3), (0.2 0.3, 0.1 0.4), (0.25 0.2, 0.3 0.3), (0.3 0.3, 0.4 0.4),(0.5 0.5, 0.6 0.6), (0.7 0.65, 0.8 0.65), (0.9 0.6, 1 0.5), (0.75 0.7, 0.7 0.8), (0.7 0.8, 0.6 0.9), (0.75 0.7, 0.8 0.8), (0.8 0.8, 0.9 0.9))</se:WellKnownName>
<se:Stroke>
<se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#0070FF</se:SvgParameter>
<se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
</se:Stroke>
</se:Mark>
<se:Size>16</se:Size>
</se:Graphic>
</se:GraphicFill>
</se:Fill>
</se:PolygonSymbolizer>
</se:Rule>
```

Geometry Generator on QGIS

```
geom_from_wkt('MULTILINESTRING((0 0, 0.1 0.1), (0.2 0.15, 0.3 0.15), (0.4 0.1, 0.5 0), (0.25 0.2, 0.2 0.3), (0.2 0.3, 0.1 0.4), (0.25 0.2, 0.3 0.3), (0.3 0.3, 0.4 0.4),(0.5 0.5, 0.6 0.6), (0.7 0.65, 0.8 0.65), (0.9 0.6, 1 0.5), (0.75 0.7, 0.7 0.8), (0.7 0.8, 0.6 0.9), (0.75 0.7, 0.8 0.8), (0.8 0.8, 0.9 0.9))')
```

I've tried using the Geometry Generator to solve this issue.

But it tends to display in the fixed upper-left corner of the screen, as shown below:

[image]

How can I make it display in QGIS in the same manner?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Can you share the SLD file publicly or does it contain proprietary or private information or content?

Comment: @bugmenot12 ok, Code has been added.